Making API call without cert validation
I am trying to call external API similar to what I do in Postman using OAuth2. In Postman I call \token endpoint then use Bearere token to call other endpoints. SSL certificate verification setting is OFF in Postman.
I have config as below and getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset exception. Based on other answer I have set TrustManager too. What I might be missing? And is there a way to debug so I get more specific error on why its failing?
@Configuration
public class MySecurityConfig {
  
  @Bean
  ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations(....) {
    ClientRegistration reg = ....
    return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(reg);
  }

  @Bean
  WebClient webClient(ResctiveClientRegistrationRepositoy cr) {
    InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService cs = new IMROAACS(cr);
    AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager acm = new ACSROAACM(cr, cs);
    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client = new SOAACEFF(acm);
    oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("my-client");

    SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trsutManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(t -> t.sslContext(sslCtx));

    return WebClient.builder()
           .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
           .filter(oauth2Client)
           .build();
   }
}

Any suggestion?

You can turn if off How to disable SSL certificate verification using Webflux Web Client Spring Boot or you can ask Copilot to write you some code to read server certs into a truststore.

-Djavax.net.debug=ssl will log java's SSL handshake. This will be verbose. Clear your logs immediately before the connection attempt so you can see only the relevant part.

@K.Nicholas - As shown in my sample code above I believe I have same config and it is still valiating certificate. However I am able to disable with RestTemplate as shown here so something "extra" neede for WebClient?
